# I want to create a 1g well in space-time curvature. How much energy would I need?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, mass-energy

Hypothetical scenario:

I want to create a block of energy with 3cm^3 of volume in order to generate a "gravity well" of 1g around it (measured close to its surface).

How much energy would I need to concentrate in that block in order to bend the fabric of space-time in its vicinity?

Ps. This block of energy could be a sphere with near-perfect reflecting inner walls and strong and dense radiation inside, making up most of the energy as momentum.

Comment: Just use $E = mc^2$.

Comment: Where do I account for the size of the block? Where do I account for the 1g acceleration? What should I put in *m*?

Comment: One can roughly do this by using $g = GM/r^2$, where $g$ is gravity acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making what I commented more complete:

If your ball is fully spherical, the gravitational acceleration at a distance $r$ from the block can be computed:
$$
g = \frac{GM}{r^2}
$$

Since you have energy instead of mass, make the conversion using $E = mc^2$. Then:
$$
g = \frac{GE}{r^2c^2}
$$

It worths mention that this is only true for the weak-gravity limit. Because we used newton gravity to do this.

Comment: Hmmm, how do I account for the block size? I think that 1kg of mass in 1cm^3 is much weaker at space distortion than 1kg in 0.0001mm correct? So it means less volume = less energy.

Comment: @PedroD Nop. 1 joule of energy in 1cm³ and 1 joule of energy in 1Km³, is 1 joule. =). As you can see.. same energy in both cases: 1 joule. The difference is the concentration. 1 joule is 1cm³ has a greater energy density than the other. But its the same energy.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Makes sense.

Btw let me share this with you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkvo-DrU2gM :) it is somewhat related to this question.